# Subclass UISlider: override or disable built-in haptic feedback?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a subclass of `UISlider` and I wish to override (specifically, disable) the built-in haptic feedback that it generates whenever the thumb reaches the ends of the track. I have my own methods of feedback that I have put into it and they obviously conflict.

I almost always post code with my question but I don't know if that would be of any use because I don't know where this would be done if it's even possible (without creating a slider from absolute scratch by subclassing `UIControl`). I can post the entire slider subclass but that doesn't seem like it would help but I will if asked.

Answer (score 1):

This does not appear to be possible. I would checkout some open source copies of UISlider or build your own from scratch. I have built them from scratch before and they are not too complicated. Here is a [list](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#slider) of some open source implementations.